# Where am I wrong in following reasoning?

Tags: derivatives, optimization, convex-optimization

Suppose we have a function $$g(x)=[f(x)]^n.$$ Further assume that the function has a unique critical point (maxima or minima). If we want to get the cirtical value of $x$ then we have to differentiate $g(x)$ and equate it to zero. But for function of the above form it could also mean that we put $f(x)=0$ since $g'(x)=n(f(x))^{n-1}f'(x)=0.$ So can we conclude that the minimum point of $g(x)$ will be for a value of $x$ for which $f(x)=0$. If this is wrong reasoning then please guide me where I am wrong. I will be very thankful to you.

One more thing. Since $g(x)$ is equal to multiple products of same function hence can we conclude that $g(x)$ will achieve minimum (or maximum) value when $f(x)$ achieves minimum (or maximum) value. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is some merit to your reasoning, but it is not the full picture. By the chain rule you correctly have

$$g'(x) = n (f(x))^{n-1} f'(x) = 0.$$

Now, for $g'(x)$ to equal zero, it suffices for $f(x)$ to be equal to zero, $\textbf{or}$ it suffices for $f'(x) = 0$. In other words, the critical points of $g(x)$ occur at the zeros of $f(x)$ and the critical points of $f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So if the function $g(x)$ is convex or concave then it means that zeros of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ will occur at same point (same value of $x$)?

Comment: For $g(x)$ to be concave, we need $g''(x) \geq 0$, so you would need to compute $g''(x)$ using more chain/product rules.

Comment: well that is true if the function is concave and i think the reverse will be true if the function is convex. But my question is about the roots of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ if $g(x)$ is convex or concave. Do they have same value?

Comment: I don't immediately see why $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ must have the same roots if $g''(x) \geq 0$. You can edit your question to give a reason why you think this may be true, but I am not sure.

Comment: Assume that $g(x)$ is convex. Then there is only single point where the derivative of $g(x)$ ($g'(x)=(nf(x))^{n-1}f'(x)=0$) is zero. Now if $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ have different roots than it will mean that the derivative of $g(x)$ is zero at two different places. I hope my reasoning made sense. However, if it is wrong then please clarify where exactly I am wrong. Thank you.